# Jquery .load() doesn't give HTML back (with a " " space in the URL!)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I am working on a webshop for school.I'm trying to make an `jquery/ajax` cart system.

Now this is my `jquery.load();` code

```
//LOAD PHP FUNCTION TO ADD TO CART
        $("#cart_page").load("cart.php?command=addToCart&productID="+productID+"&size="+size+"&amount="+amount+"&product_name="+product_name+"");
```

This is the cart.php file:

```
<?php

//ADD PRODUCTS TO CART
if($_GET['command'] == 'addToCart'){
    /********* START SESSION *********/
    session_start();

    if($_GET['productID'] == "" || $_GET['amount'] < 1 || $_GET['size'] == "" || $_GET['product_name'] == "") return;

    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);

    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);

        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            if($_GET['productID'] == $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
                if($_GET['size'] == $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['size'] ){
                    $product_exists = 1;
                }   
            }
        }

        if($product_exists != 1){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid'] = $_GET['productID'];
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['product_name'] = $_GET['product_name'];
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['amount'] = $_GET['amount'];
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['size'] = $_GET['size'];
        }

    }else{

        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid'] = $_GET['productID'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['product_name'] = $_GET['product_name'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['amount'] = $_GET['amount'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['size'] = $_GET['size'];

    }

if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
$max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
$cart = <<<EOD
<div class="cart_page">
    <div class="cart_product_line">
    $max
        <ul>

EOD;
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $arrayID = $i;
            $cart_productID = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $cart_productName = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['product_name'];
            $cart_amount = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['amount'];
            $cart_size = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['size'];

$cart.= <<<EOD
            <li>$arrayID</li>
            <li>$cart_productID</li>
            <li id="$cart_productID">$cart_productName</li>
            <li class="amount">$cart_amount</li>
            <li class="size">$cart_size</li>
EOD;
        }

$cart.= <<<EOD
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
EOD;
    }
}
echo $cart;

?>
```

Now it does everything i want it to. But the result it gives in `'echo $cart.php'` doesn
't get displayed in my index.php

can you guys help me out please?

PS:

if i go to:

> cart.php?command=addToCart&productID=28&amount=10&size=12&product_name=Test

It gives this back

```
1
0
28
Test
10
12
```

in HTML so the script works and gives html back!
I'm doing the same with loading products and there it works like a charm.

Comment: Dainis, it doesn't need to. It will put the response into the #cart_page element according to jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @DainisAbols Can you explain what you mean? if no response is specified it should give the whole page back it generates right?
This is the way i load my products into index.php and this works like a charm.
`$("#cart_page").load("products.php?id="+productID+"");`

Comment: Try using something like: `$("#cart_page").load("cart.php?blahblahblah", function (responseText, textStatus, req) { if (textStatus == "error") { alert("fail"); } else { alert("success"); } });` and see what alerts, if anything.

Comment: @Ian I've done what you said.
`//LOAD PHP FUNCTION TO ADD TO CART
   $("#cart_page").load("cart.php?command=addToCart&productID="+productID+"&size="+size+"&amount="+amount+"&product_name="+product_name+"", function () { alert("success"); }).error(function () { alert("error"); });`

and got 'Succes' back send at me in a pop-up box. so errors on loading the script.

Is it possible that you can only load one page ? i can't seem to find the error here

Comment: @JeffreyBouva Sorry, I edited my comment like a minute after I submitted it. I realized the methods for determining if it was success/error was different. I was thinking of how `$.get`/`$.post` is used. Try what my comment says now

Comment: @Ian still gives back succes! see my comment on answere below in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So So Stupid..

The `$product_name` that I generated was from a database.

This name had a " " space in it.

What this did was it gave the success of loading the script but because it had a " " space in the URL jQuery sees it as a incorrect URL and doesn't embed the script into the page.

What I find strange is that it didn't give me any error back!?

Thank you guys so much for helping me out!

Comment: urlencode the values that you pull from the database in future ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that everything you have said is true then there are several things that might go wrong here (in order of likelyhood):

1. Is the AJAX call being made to another domain? If so this won't work unless you output some special headers.
2. jQuery.load will fail if the element you are targetting does not exist. So double check that you have the #cart_page element on your page.
3. The AJAX page is not returning the correct HTTP response code. This will be visible in your console. But you can get more information by expanding your code to:

   `$("#cart_page").load("cart.php?command=addToCart&productID="+productID+"&size="+size+"&amount="+amount+"&product_name="+product_name+"", function(response, status, xhr) {
     if (status == "error") {
       console.log("Error code :" + xhr.status); // error code
       console.log ("Error text :" + xhr.statusText); // error text
     }
   });`
4. Some other JS errors. As we cannot see all of your code this is hard to see. Check the console for any errors and add them to your first post.

(Sorry for the formatting of the code in point 3. I've no idea how to embed code in a list using this syntax. An indent doesn't work)

Comment: Heey Dean, Thanks for the answer

1. It's on the same domain. No cross-domain request.
2. Thanks for the heads up. I have tested with `$("#cart_page").load("products.php?id="+productID+"");`
And this will load all the products into the div cart_page
3. console is totaly empty, no error or so.

Comment: Go to the "Network" tab in Web Inspector (in Chrome) and debug the actual HTTP request. Do you see anything in the "Response"? i.e. you should see the same output as if you went to it directly.

Comment: @Dead really good idea of the Network tab!
in preview i see the same output as the cart.php directly gives me
so i think i can assume that the header are send correctly